# Is there a gcc flag to catch integer truncation?

Tags: c, gcc, floating-accuracy

Is there a `gcc` flag to signal a warning/error when I try to put a `double` value into an `int` variable? I currently have `-Wall -Wextra -Werror` set but I still don't get warned when I (for instance) pass a `double` to an `int` parameter, even though I'm losing information.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the [`-Wconversion`](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.2/gcc/Warning-Options.html#Warning-Options) option. From GCC's manual *(emphasis mine)*:

> Warn for implicit conversions that may alter a value. **This includes
>   conversions between real and integer**, like abs (x) when x is double;
>   conversions between signed and unsigned, like unsigned ui = -1; and
>   conversions to smaller types, like sqrtf (M_PI). Do not warn for
>   explicit casts like abs ((int) x) and ui = (unsigned) -1, or if the
>   value is not changed by the conversion like in abs (2.0). Warnings
>   about conversions between signed and unsigned integers can be disabled
>   by using -Wno-sign-conversion.

This is the state uptill GCC 4.8.2, while from GCC 4.9.0 you may also use [`-Wfloat-conversion`](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html#Warning-Options) for the same.

Comment: This is not ideal. It also raises warnings about signed/unsigned conversion, which is not about a truncation and which I don't need. Wish there's a flag for truncation only.

Comment: Did you try `-Wfloat-conversion`? The one @unwind's answer is suggesting.

Comment: @PengheGeng You can get truncation only by adding `-Wno-sign-conversion`. However `-Wconversion` still seems to be useless IMO as it also warns for explicit conversion, so basically disallows all casts to a smaller type. It also warns on implicit conversion of literals so `my_u8 += 1` is an error because `1` is an `int`.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, use the [`-Wfloat-conversion`](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html#index-Wfloat-conversion-475) option:

> `-Wfloat-conversion`
>
> Warn for implicit conversions that reduce the precision of a real value. This includes conversions from real to integer, and from higher precision real to lower precision real values. This option is also enabled by `-Wconversion`.

Comment: I think this is only within float values for loss of precision, will it warn for _double to an int_?

Comment: @legends2k I didn't test it now, but I think the wording that I quoted is clear enough (both `float` and `double` are "real").

Comment: I can not get that to work either on Coliru, I would just stick with `-Wconversion`

Comment: I'm getting an "unrecognised option" when passing `-Wfloat-conversion` to `gcc`, it may have been removed in favour of `-Wconversion`.

Comment: In [GCC 4.8.2's manual](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.2/gcc/Warning-Options.html#Warning-Options) it's not there, but in the upcoming [4.9.0 it's going to be there](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html#Warning-Options). Here's [the bug page](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=53001) which confirms the addition of this option in 4.9.