# 255 char. instead of 1023, Unable to set reference voltage

Tags: c, avr, adc, atmega16

I am using ATmega16 in my project. I want to get the value=**1023 when I give 5V** as input, and 0 when input = 0. The readADC function reads the particular channel of micro-controller ADC. The frequency of my clock is 4MHz. But on reading the input, I'm **getting 255** as the maximum value instead of 1023. 
Someone who knows about avr programming can help !!!

My code:

```
#include <avr/delay.h>
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <avr/interrupt.h>

unsigned char ReadADC(unsigned char ch)
{
   ch = ch&0b00000111;
   ADMUX&=0xF8;
   ADMUX |= ch;
   ADCSRA |= (1<<ADSC);
   while(ADCSRA & (1<<ADSC);   //wait for conversion to complete
   return(ADC);
}

int main(void)
{
   SegDataDDR = 0xFF;
   SegCntrlDDR = 0xF3;
   SegCntrlPort = 0xF3;
   SegDataPort = 0x00;

ADMUX = (1<<REFS0) | (0<<REFS1);
ADCSRA = (1<<ADEN) | (1<<ADPS2) | (1<<ADPS0);   // ADEN set to turn ADC on
// clock frequency divided by 32 for operable 125KHz frequency

while(1) 
{ 
   ADCSRA |= (1<<ADSC);    // start conversion
   unsigned char value = ReadADC(0);    // Reads the value of the ADC
}
```

Comment: 1023 is too large to fit in an `unsigned char`. What you're getting is the least significant byte of 1023, which is 255.

Comment: Hint: try an `unsigned short` or `unsigned int` instead of `unsigned char`

Comment: I have tried float, int and others, but it doesn't work Please suggest appropriate datatype, if that is the only problem!!!

Comment: @Levi I have tried both unsigned int and unsigned short, but it doesn't worked

Comment: @Yash: Is it possible that the `ADC` register is only 8 bits long? That could be the issue

Comment: What do you mean by ADC register ?? Multiplying value will not increase the resolution.

Comment: @Yash Read a data sheet, specifying the processor's registers. The symbol `ADC` in your code is a reference to a hardware register, part of the A/D converter.

Comment: @Yash: [Here](http://www.atmel.com/images/doc2466.pdf) you go

Comment: @Levi - multiplication will not solve the problem of resolution. I want 10bit resolution, not 8 bit.

Comment: Maybe, in the future, have a look at your compiler warnings, see e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22198305/is-there-a-gcc-flag-to-catch-integer-truncation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code, the line

```
unsigned char value = ReadADC(0);
```

is restricting you to only 8 bits. You need to change the type of `value` to something larger, like an `unsigned short`, which can hold 16 bits worth of data. If you make this change, you must also change the definition of `ReadADC` to

```
unsigned short ReadADC(unsigned char ch)
```

Comment: He will have to change `unsigned char ReadADC(unsigned char ch)` too.

Comment: There is one more problem, I am not able to set the maximum reference voltage. I have applied 5V at AVcc and a capicator to ground at Aref. But 5V output is also giving 1023 (max. value) and 3V output is also doing the same.

Comment: @Yash: That is an entirely different question, and is more suitable for [electronics stack exchange](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score -1):

Replace unsigned char by unit16_t